# Add new functions from string to window without providing a name

Tags: javascript, scope

Say I have the following:

```
( new Function( `return function a(){ console.log('hi!'); }` ) )();
```

This returns a function, but I want to make it 'callable' at the window level without having to assign it to a variable.

I'm guessing that this can't be done because the step where the engine handles definitions is already done?

Comment: You can assign properties dynamically to the `window` object, but it sounds like you're doing something very unsafe. Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming you know what you're doing with that approach.*

You can add the function to one attribute before the return step.

```
return (window['fn'] = function a(){ console.log('hi!'); })
```

```js
( new Function( `return (window['fn'] = function a(){ console.log('hi!'); })` ) )();

fn();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```